# How to apply texture for 3d model from mixamo?

Tags: xcode, arkit

I downloaded 3model from here https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/cartoon-boy-rigged-character-3d-model-1214430, than I add animation on mixamo site and after that add this model to Xcode! How to correct apply texture for model in xcode, because it’s has a lot of texture for shoes, body, eyes and e.t.c ?

Comment: How did you import the model in mixamo?

Comment: press button "upload a character" and drop file .obj, than add animation and download as file with extension .dae

Answer (score 3):

Try to do the following:

- Export the model in obj format without the textures
- Export the material and textures in the same folder (.mtl, .png, etc...)
- Zip all the content
- Upload the entire zip in Mixamo

Comment: I made, how you said, but how to understand which texture I should apply ? https://ufile.io/eox64l2h

Comment: Which software are you using for exporting the model?

Comment: I download model from turbosquid.com, than export to mixamo

Comment: As I see there is also the fbx format, have you tried to import that one?

Comment: Surely good to give a try.
The fbx format has the textures embedded, I am afraid that will not work because the fbx contains also animation information and I don't know if mixamo replace all this information or goes in conflict.
Anyway, you can download blender software import and export all the files

Comment: I tried, but maximo can not load this zip .In which format I should import in  blender and export than?

Comment: Try to import as fbx format in Blender then do File->Export-> Wavefront (Obj) .
In the bottom left you should see the options, export firstly with just these options ticked:
- "Object as OBJ objects"
- "Include edges"
- "Write Normals"
- "Include UVs"
- "Write Materials"

You should find all the files that you need, then zip and try to import in mixamo!

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked in Unity when I was losing hope!